# How to use jquery each() function within horseman's [phantom for node.js] evaluate() to simulate multiple clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

Well, I need to click on many links using horseman using a loop.
e.g.
HTML file:

```
<ul class="conn-list">
   <li><a> link 1 </a></li>
   <li><a> link 2 </a></li>
   <li><a> link 3 </a></li>
</ul>
```

I already tried something like this (.js file [using node.js]):

```
var Horseman = require("node-horseman");
var horseman = new Horseman();
var $ = require ("jquery");

horseman.viewport(3200, 1800)
    .open('url')

    /* some code to navigate the headless browser*/

    .evaluate(function clickLinks() {
        var $links = $("a"); //I am supposing that are not other <a> tags on the page.
        $links.each(function (index, $links) {
            $(this).click();

            horseman.waitForNextPage()
                .wait(5000) //just to ensure that all the page loads before the print.
                .screenshot("new_page", index, ".png") //just to know if it works.
        });
    })
```

That's all, it compiles but doesn't take the scheenshots neither access the hyperlinks.. I don't know, maybe the answer is to use the multiple tabs support from horseman.js.. Any help is welcome for a newbie! :D Thank's for your time!

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  Would like to know if you did.

Comment: Sort of..
Actually i did the reverse logic, instead of putting the loop inside the horseman, i did put all the horseman inside a "do...while" loop, since you can't use the same horseman instance inside of itself (as i tried to do on the code above), and my tries of using a loop inside the ".evaluate" failed because it creates a new scope and do bug the  counter. It's not the most effective way to do it, i guess, it opens the headless browser a lot of times, increases the running time, but it works.. :)

Comment: The function you pass to `.evaluate()` must be self contained. You can't reference anything outside of it (i.e. `horseman`). Also, jQuery is already injected by default into the page, so `$()` would work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Horseman's `.evaluate()` method takes a function that it then converts into a string and injects into the page. The means that the function doesn't know about anything outside of it (e.x. `horseman`).

You'll get a very unhelpful error that contains:

```
global code
evaluateJavaScript@[native code]
```

You want to return the urls for your links in the function you passed to `.evaluate(fn)`, bringing those urls back into the node process and loop over them there.

Because Horseman is built on top of the Bluebird promise library, you can just call `.then()`. So, something like this:

```
horseman.viewport(3200, 1800)
  .open('url')
  .evaluate(function clickLinks() {
    var $links = $("a"); //I am supposing that are not other <a> tags on the page.
    return $links.map(function (index, $links) {
      return $(this).attr('href');
    }).get();
  })
  .then(async function (hrefs){
    // this uses async/await, but you can use some recursive function or some other async looping logic
    for(var href of hrefs) {
      // use the .open() method with the gathered href's
      await horseman.open(href)
        .wait(5000) //just to ensure that all the page loads before the print.
        .screenshot("new_page", index, ".png") //just to know if it works.
    }
  })
```